# SQL: How to use CASE in join

Tags: sql

Here is the code I am trying to use

```
SELECT
  TData.dtContractDate,
  TData.chPurchase,
  TData.nShipperID,
  TData.nSourceSiteId,
  Vendor.chShipperName,
  Vendor.chCity,
  Vendor.chState,
  Vendor.chCountry,
  Vendor.chZip 
FROM Data1.dbo.TData TData
JOIN Data1.dbo.Vendor
  ON Vendor.nShipperId = TData.nShipperID
  AND Vendor.nCompanyCode  = (CASE WHEN Vendor.nCompanyCode = '2' THEN '2' ELSE '26' END)
WHERE (TData.nCompanyCode=2) AND (TData.dtContractDate > '" 04/23/2015 12:01:00 AM')
```

I am trying to join these two tables, but if

`ncompanycode = 2 AND Vendor.nShipperId = TData.nShipperID`,

then I want to pull that data, if this doesn't exist, then I want to use

`ncompanycode = 26 and Vendor.nShipperId = TData.nShipperID`.

Right now I get duplicates for any `shipperID` that both companies have.

Here are the dummy tables and the results I am getting, I don't want duplicates for chPurchase.

**TData Table**

```
|            dtContractDate | chPurchase | nShipperID | nSourceSiteId | nCompanyCode |
|---------------------------|------------|------------|---------------|--------------|
| January, 04 2015 00:00:00 |    2547635 |        453 |      68686868 |            2 |
| January, 05 2015 00:00:00 |    2547636 |        453 |      68686868 |            2 |
| January, 06 2015 00:00:00 |    2547637 |        454 |      68686868 |            2 |
| January, 07 2015 00:00:00 |    2547638 |        454 |      68686868 |            2 |
| January, 08 2015 00:00:00 |    2547639 |        455 |      68686868 |            2 |
| January, 09 2015 00:00:00 |    2547640 |        456 |      68686868 |            2 |
```

**Vendor Table**

```
| nCompanyCode | nShipperID | chShipperName | chCity | chState | chCountry |  chZip |
|--------------|------------|---------------|--------|---------|-----------|--------|
|            2 |        453 |         Name1 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666555 |
|           26 |        453 |         Name2 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666556 |
|            2 |        454 |         Name3 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666557 |
|           26 |        455 |         Name4 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666558 |
|            2 |        455 |         Name5 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666559 |
|           26 |        456 |         Name6 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666560 |
```

**Results Table**

```
|   dtContractDate | chPurchase | nShipperID | nSourceSiteId | nCompanyCode | chShipperName | chCity | chState | chCountry |  chZip |
|------------------|------------|------------|---------------|--------------|---------------|--------|---------|-----------|--------|
| January, 04 2015 |    2547635 |        453 |      68686868 |           26 |         Name2 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666555 |
| January, 04 2015 |    2547635 |        453 |      68686868 |            2 |         Name1 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666555 |
| January, 05 2015 |    2547636 |        453 |      68686868 |           26 |         Name1 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666556 |
| January, 05 2015 |    2547636 |        453 |      68686868 |            2 |         Name2 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666556 |
| January, 06 2015 |    2547637 |        454 |      68686868 |            2 |         Name3 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666557 |
| January, 07 2015 |    2547638 |        454 |      68686868 |            2 |         Name3 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666558 |
| January, 08 2015 |    2547639 |        455 |      68686868 |            2 |         Name5 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666559 |
| January, 08 2015 |    2547639 |        455 |      68686868 |           26 |         Name5 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666559 |
| January, 09 2015 |    2547640 |        456 |      68686868 |            26 |         Name6 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666560 |
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the actual behavior vs what you expect to get. Can you post a (really small) example of the output you're getting and the output you want? You can change the values to fake ones and delete irrelevant columns if that helps.

Comment: (1) Your question is tagged "mysql", yet you are using a three-part naming convention for tables most closely associated with SQL Server.  (2) Your date comparison isn't going to work.  Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: Gordon, Thanks for the SQL MYSQL advice.   The Date comparison works perfectly, it the decision making for the company and shipperID that needs to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not use `CASE` but produces the desired result with cleaner conditionals using `COALESCE`.

I have shortened your table aliases for readability.

I have also commented out the WHERE clause involving dates because:

1. It was mal-formed and would not match any date with current typos.
2. When typos were corrected, it eliminates all rows from your sample
   data.

The SQL code uses two `LEFT JOINs` and uses `COALESCE` to choose which one to use in the `SELECT` output. When the first `JOIN` (`V`) has a `NULL` result, the output resorts to `V2`. The `V2` `JOIN` explicitly requires that the `nCompanyCode` be `26`, but any criteria can be added or removed as desired if there are multiple alternative `nCompanyCodes`.

**Query:**

```
SELECT
   T.dtContractDate
  ,T.chPurchase
  ,T.nShipperID
  ,T.nSourceSiteId
  ,COALESCE(V.chShipperName,V2.chShipperName) chShipperName
  ,COALESCE(V.chCity,V2.chCity) chCity
  ,COALESCE(V.chState, V2.chState) chState
  ,COALESCE(V.chCountry,V2.chCountry) chCountry
  ,COALESCE(V.chZip,V2.chZip) chZip
  -- Added to show what Vendor company code is being used
  ,COALESCE(V.nCompanyCode,V2.nCompanyCode) nCompanyCode
FROM TData T
LEFT JOIN Vendor V
  ON V.nShipperId = T.nShipperID
  AND V.nCompanyCode = T.nCompanyCode
LEFT JOIN Vendor V2
  ON V2.nShipperId = T.nShipperID
  AND V2.nCompanyCode <> T.nCompanyCode
  AND V2.nCompanyCode = 26
-- Commented out this WHERE clause because it eliminates all rows
-- WHERE T.dtContractDate > '04/23/2015 12:01:00 AM'
```

**Sample Output:**

```
|   dtContractDate | chPurchase | nShipperID | nSourceSiteId | chShipperName | chCity | chState | chCountry |  chZip | nCompanyCode |
|------------------|------------|------------|---------------|---------------|--------|---------|-----------|--------|--------------|
| January, 04 2015 |    2547635 |        453 |      68686868 |         Name1 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666555 |            2 |
| January, 05 2015 |    2547636 |        453 |      68686868 |         Name1 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666555 |            2 |
| January, 06 2015 |    2547637 |        454 |      68686868 |         Name3 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666557 |            2 |
| January, 07 2015 |    2547638 |        454 |      68686868 |         Name3 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666557 |            2 |
| January, 08 2015 |    2547639 |        455 |      68686868 |         Name5 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666559 |            2 |
| January, 09 2015 |    2547640 |        456 |      68686868 |         Name6 | Dallas |      TX |        US | 666560 |           26 |
```

You can play with the SQLFiddle for this example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d6d9/5/0).

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to be working.  I do need the where statement to limit date/time, I just need to put into the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to join on the two tables where the shipper IDs are equal *and then* select all the rows from that set where the company code is equal to the value you want. Also, it seems like you don't want that `WHERE (TData.nCompanyCode=2)` condition, since you're already trying to select where the company code is 2 OR 26 above. Try this:

```
SELECT TData.dtContractDate, TData.chPurchase, TData.nShipperID, 
TData.nSourceSiteId,  Vendor.chShipperName, Vendor.chCity,     
Vendor.chState,  Vendor.chCountry, Vendor.chZip 
FROM Data1.dbo.TData TData
Join Data1.dbo.Vendor on Vendor.nShipperId = TData.nShipperID
WHERE Vendor.nCompanyCode  = (case when Vendor.nCompanyCode = '2' then     
'2' else '26' end)
AND (TData.dtContractDate > '" 04/23/2015     
12:01:00 AM')
```

Comment: I want all records on the TData table for company =2 (not records where company = 26).   But I want the shipper info from vendor where company = 2 and shipids match, but if that combination isn't there, I want the shipper info for company =26 and shipids match.